# VBA - Removing empty rows in - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Tags: vba, excel

I have around 50 rows on my sheet and I am editing them using a VBA macro.
When I store the last used row in the following format

```
NewLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

NewLastRow came up with row 65, despite there being nothing in the rows.
So I incorporated a passage of code to select the active range, and delete rows which have no content.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

'Deletes the row within the selection if the row has no data.
Dim i As Long

'Turn off aspects which could slow down process.
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False

    'Delete backwards.
    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
            Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

This works, however it takes a really long time. How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you can improve in your code:

1) You are iterating through all the rows. It is over 1 million iterations in Excel 2007+. Usually there are no more than a few thousands of non-empty rows. So, the code would work faster if you first found the index of the last non-empty row and then used this index as a limit in your `For ... Next` loop.

2) Deleting rows is quite time-consuming operation, so if it is possible it should be consolidated into a single operationg. You can collect all the rows to be removed into a single range by using `Union` function and then remove all of them with a single command.

Below is the complete code to achieve your task:

```
Public Sub deleteRows()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim row As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Set wks = Excel.ActiveSheet
    lastRow = lastNonEmptyRow(wks)


    With wks

        For row = 1 To lastRow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(row)) = 0 Then

                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = .Rows(row)
                Else
                    Set rng = Excel.Union(rng, .Rows(row))
                End If

            End If
        Next row

    End With



    'In order to avoid Run-time error check if [rng] range is not empty, before removing it.
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Call rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If



End Sub
```

**NOTE**. In order to make this code working properly, you need to include [function to find the last non-empty row in Excel worksheet](http://mielk.pl/en/download/code/worksheet/lastNonEmptyRow.txt) into your code.

Comment: Great thank you @mielk for that, top marks for effort. I actually didn't use your functions here --> http://mielk.pl/en/download/code/worksheet/lastNonEmptyRow.txt
  Instead I changed 
                                                               
lastRow = lastNonEmptyRow(wks)
----------------                       
to 
---------------                    
lastRow = NewLastRow

Answer (score 0):

```
You can remove it by following code :

On Error Resume Next
worksheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: 1) This statement: `worksheet.Columns("A:A")` would cause Compilation error unless he has variable `worksheet` declared.

2) Your code would remove too many rows. What if cell A1 is empty, but there is some value in B1? This row would be removed by your code, but it shouldn't since it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I just used in a similar project that was identifying too many rows beyond the actual data.

```
RowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Returns 67, when it should be 54

For i = RowCount To 2 Step -1
    j = ws.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(i & ":" & i))
    If j > 0 Then
        RowCount = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print "RowCount = " & RowCount 'Returns 54 as intended
```

Theoretically, you could do this again for columns, too.  No need for that crazy attachment referenced in other posts.  Note -- this doesn't fix your UsedRange, it just sets the proper row count (which is all I used UsedRange for, anyway).  I found that deleting rows beyond the data doesn't seem to affect UsedRange, anyway.  That seems to be your issue--there are 50 rows of continuous data, and 15 more rows of nothing at the bottom that are included in UsedRange.  The above example will get you the proper final row.  (You could make this a Do While loop as well, just remember to adjust i as you go).

The above solution works for when you can't rely on a single column to always have data.  Otherwise, if you know a column will have data (say a Key, for example), you can move your active cell to the bottom of the sheet, then xlUp to the first cell that has data (which in theory is the last row).  Similar to highlighting a row, pressing Ctrl Down, selecting the cell in col A, and pressing Ctrl Up.  That code looks like:

```
LastRow = ws.Columns(1).Rows.Count
LastRow = ws.Cells(LastRow, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```